# Unexpected error, while copy query results to table using google java bigquery api for GAE

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to copy query result to a new table, but I'm getting an error :

```
Copy
11:13am
query results to 49077933619:TelcoNG.table
Errors:

Unexpected. Please try again.
Job ID: job_090d08f69c8e4199afeca131b5279393
Start Time: 11:13am, 12 Aug 2013
End Time: 11:13am, 12 Aug 2013
Copy Source: 49077933619:_8dc46c0daeb9142a91aa374aa59d615c3703e024.anon17d88e0e_0960_4510_9740_b753109050f4
Destination Table: 49077933619:TelcoNG.table
```

I get this error since last Thursday (8 Aug 2013).
This functionality has worked perfect for over an year.

Are there any changes in the API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there is a bug in detecting which datacenters a table created as the result of a query has been replicated to. You're doing the copy operation very soon after the query finished, and before the results have finished replicating. As I mentioned, this is a bug and we should fix it very soon.

As a short-term workaround, you can either wait a few minutes between the query and the copy operation, or you can set a destination table on your query, so you don't need to do the copy operation at all.

Comment: This morning everything was OK. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: OK... well the underlying issue wasn't fixed until this afternoon. It should go out in next week's release.